# How to find $y_u?$

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

In the paper *[Semi-supervised learning by mixed label propagation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1619645.1619750)* Wei Tong and Rong Jin define

$S$ as the similarity(adjacency) matrix
$D = \operatorname{diag}(D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_n)$ where $D_i = \sum_{j=1}^nS_{i,j}$
class assignment $\textbf{y} = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$

Given the class labels of $n_l$ examples, $\widehat{y}_l = (\widehat{y}_1, \widehat{y}_2,\ldots,\widehat{y}_{nl})$, the optimal class assignment **y** is found by minimizing the energy function

[image: problem]

where $E(S, \textbf{y}) = \sum_{i, j=1}^n S_{ij}(y_i - y_j)^2 = \textbf{y}^TL
\textbf{y}, L = D - S$.
How to find $y_u$? I have tried the following.

\begin{align}
E(S, \textbf{y}) & = \begin{bmatrix}
y_l & y_u
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
L^{l, l} & L^{l, u}\\
L^{u, l} & L^{u, u}\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_l \\
y_u
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
& = \begin{bmatrix}
y_l & y_u
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
L^{l, l}y_l + L^{l, u}y_u\\
L^{u, l}y_l + L^{u, u}y_u\\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
& = y_l^TL^{l, l}y_l + y_l^TL^{l, u}y_u + y_u^TL^{u, l}y_l + y_u^TL^{u, u}y_u
\end{align}

when I take the derivative w.r.t $y_u$  I don't understand how to differentiate $y_u^TL^{u, l}y_l$. Following this [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/312083/336994),

$$(y_u + h)^TL^{u, l}y_l - y_u^TL^{u, l}y_l = h^TL^{u, l}y_l$$

Now, how to divide by $h$.

Also if this is not the correct way, how to find $y_u$ then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20712/336994) answer.
As $L$ is symmetric,
\begin{align}
\frac{d (E(S, \textbf{y}))}{d y_u} = 0 + y_l^TL^{l,u} + (L^{u,l}y_l)^T + y_u^TL^{u, u} + (L^{u, u}y_u)^T = 0
\\ 
2 y_l^T L^{L, u} + 2y_u^T L^{u, u} = 0
\\
y_u = -(L^{u,u})^{-1}L^{u,l}y_l
\end{align}